# How can I run multiple commands with PSQL client

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have been trying to run multiple command via psql client to connect to remote database and run some commands in a single line , but it seems this isn't possible ?

I tried to run below command and it give me straight error after executing the first command.
I have all bash variable set in environment.

```
PGPASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD} psql -h ${REMOTE_HOST} -U postgres -d ${SOME_DATABASE} -c 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";' -c "CREATE USER '$DB_USER' WITH PASSWORD '${DB_PASSWORD}';" -c 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "${DB_DATABASE}" TO "${DB_USER}";'
```

when I run this it looks like only first command got successful , I read the instruction from psql help `-c, --command=COMMAND    run only single command (SQL or internal) and exit` .

But Is there a way to make use of bash pipe or backslash to use it this way ?

Comment: Put them in a file and start `psql` with the `-f ..` parameter

Comment: Yes, use a file or, if you really don't want to do that, use HEREDOC syntax from stdin.

Comment: with file I know , but I really want to execute this whole with a single line really. So I am aware of HEREDOC and file approach but just don't want to do it that way. This has to run in a container so I just want some bash approach to it as much as possible.

Comment: What is preventing you from putting multiple commands separated by semicolon in the `-c` argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks , I think I was just able to pass the multiple commands via the below. Anyone sees this be an issue if I have different type of names like dash(-) and multiple dash in DB name and User name?

My bash variables were set before.
So the below solution fails if the user name or database name has dash '-'. Also DB_PASSWORD has to come with single inverted comma's.

```
echo 'CREATE USER '${USER}' WITH PASSWORD '$DB_PASSWORD'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE '${DB}' TO "${USER}";' | PGPASSWORD=mysecretpassword psql -U postgres -d ${DB}
CREATE ROLE
GRANT
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray backslash in there which is surely mucking stuff up.

> -c "CREATE USER '$DB_USER'..."

The name of the user needs to be either unquoted, or quoted with double quotes.  Quoting it with single quotes is not allowed.

> -c 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "${DB_DATABASE}"...'

shell variable substitution does not occur inside strings set off by outermost single quote marks, so this is referencing the literal string `"${DB_DATABASE}"`.

If you need the literal double quote marks and variable substitution as well, you can either use single quotes but stopping them before the variable, picking up after.  Or use double quotes, but escaping the literal double quotes. (This is with `bash`, I don't know about other shells)

```
$ export foo=bar-baz
$ echo 'here is "'$foo'" within quotes'
here is "bar-baz" within quotes
$ echo "here is \"$foo\" within quotes"
here is "bar-baz" within quotes
```

Comment: sorry @jjanes , I corrected my typo. on the part of USER and DB names , what do you recommend when I have different set of names for user and database , like I have dash(-) between the names for databases and users ex: `foo-bar` , `pc-jb` etc. any suggestions on that?

Comment: yes that's correct @jjanes. Thanks I did the same and it works now in a single line command.